# ツールバー"CSV/並び替え"の中の"空白"を選択すると、行番号 1 が表示から消える

Tags: emeditor

Ver. 20.0.3を利用です
※ver 20.0.2でも発生していた

ツールバー"CSV/並び替え"の中の"空白"を選択すると
行番号 1 が表示から消える

編集中のテキストには影響がないようですが、CSVツールバーの"空白"を選ぶと 行番号 1　が消えます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

CSVツールバーの"空白" というのは、「ヘディング 1-4」のことでしょうか? そうだとすると、こちらでも再現しましたので、次のバージョンで修正します。お返事が遅くなり申し訳ありませんでした。